# Retrieve data from database using values from multiple/one dropdownlist

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to bind data to a grid view from 3 different drop downlist.

The user could choose 1 value from 1 DDL or from the 2 DDL or from the 3 DDL then a SQL query will be generated to retrieve data from database and bind it to my GV.

All what I need is a perfect SQL query or a function that will accept the values chosen from D1,D2,D3 taking into consideration that the user could choose from D1, D2, D3 or a multiple of DDL

```html
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="height: 265px">
    
        welcome to this page
        <br />
        here u r allowed to search for a car with available attributes
        <br />
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="MODELCODE"   ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="MODELCODE" HeaderText="MODELCODE" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="MODELCODE" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Manufacturercountry" HeaderText="Manufacturercountry" SortExpression="Manufacturercountry" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="modelname" HeaderText="modelname" SortExpression="modelname" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="modelcolor" HeaderText="modelcolor" SortExpression="modelcolor" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="dailyhirringrate" HeaderText="dailyhirringrate" SortExpression="dailyhirringrate" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="sellingprice" HeaderText="sellingprice" SortExpression="sellingprice" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="numberofcars" HeaderText="numberofcars" SortExpression="numberofcars" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="currentmielage" HeaderText="currentmielage" SortExpression="currentmielage" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="enginesize" HeaderText="enginesize" SortExpression="enginesize" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="liecensenumber" HeaderText="liecensenumber" SortExpression="liecensenumber" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource9" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MALAK1ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [CARMODEL] WHERE (([Manufacturercountry] = @Manufacturercountry) AND ([modelname] = @modelname))">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="country" DefaultValue="&quot;&quot;" Name="Manufacturercountry" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList2" DefaultValue="&quot;&quot;" Name="modelname" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="buy a car" />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="rent a car" />
        <br />
        <br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    
    </div>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; country&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:DropDownList ID="country" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"   DataTextField="Manufacturercountry" DataValueField="Manufacturercountry"  AppendDataBoundItems ="true">
            <asp:listitem selected="True" text="" value=""></asp:listitem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MALAK1ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [Manufacturercountry] FROM [CARMODEL]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; modelname :&nbsp;
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="modelname" DataValueField="modelname">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MALAK1ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [modelname] FROM [CARMODEL]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; color&nbsp;
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" DataTextField="modelcolor" DataValueField="modelcolor" style="margin-left: 12px">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MALAK1ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [modelcolor] FROM [CARMODEL]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; daily H.rate :&nbsp;
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4" DataTextField="dailyhirringrate" DataValueField="dailyhirringrate">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource4" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MALAK1ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [dailyhirringrate] FROM [CARMODEL]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; selling price&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList5" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource5" DataTextField="sellingprice" DataValueField="sellingprice">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource5" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MALAK1ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [sellingprice] FROM [CARMODEL]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; E.size&nbsp;
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList7" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource6" DataTextField="enginesize" DataValueField="enginesize">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource6" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MALAK1ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [enginesize] FROM [CARMODEL]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; mileage:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList6" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource7" DataTextField="currentmielage" DataValueField="currentmielage">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource7" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MALAK1ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [currentmielage] FROM [CARMODEL]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList8" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource8" DataTextField="liecensenumber" DataValueField="liecensenumber">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource8" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MALAK1ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [liecensenumber] FROM [CARMODEL]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="check for cars" />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button4" runat="server" Text="Button" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button5" runat="server" style="margin-left: 365px" Text="Button5" />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="Button6" runat="server" style="margin-left: 134px" Text="Button" Width="109px" />
    </form>
```

```
 Protected Sub Button5_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click

    If country.SelectedValue = "" Then
        conn = obj.Connection
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select * from CARMODEL where modelname = @mdn and modelcolor = @mdc and dailyhirringrate = @dhr and sellingprice = @spr  and liecensenumber = @ln", conn)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mdn", DropDownList2.SelectedValue)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mdc", DropDownList3.SelectedValue)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dhr", DropDownList4.SelectedValue)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@spr", DropDownList5.SelectedValue)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ln", DropDownList8.SelectedValue)



        Dim dst As New DataSet()
        Dim dt As New DataTable("frmcntry")

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

        Dim dadapt As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        dadapt.Fill(dt)


        GridView1.DataSource = dt
        GridView1.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: *"all what I need is a perfect sqlquerry or a function"*. We're not here to write your code for you. If you have no idea how to write the query then you haven't done enough research yet. If you do have an idea then do what you think is appropriate and, if it doesn't work, then there IS a need to post THAT code and explain how it's actual behaviour differs from your expectation.

Answer (score 0):

The key will be an Entity Data Model combined with LINQ TO SQL

If you setup your program with an EDM to your database than it becomes really easy.

Example:

```
using container as new yourEDMContainer
Dim yourquery as IQueryable(Of yourdatatableelementclass) = container.yourtableSet

If DDL1wasselected Then
   yourquery = yourquery.where(Function(v) v.thevalue1tocompare = DDL1value)
End If

If DDL2wasselected Then
   yourquery = yourquery.where(Function(v) v.thevalue2tocompare = DDL2value)
End If

 If DDL3wasselected Then
   yourquery = yourquery.where(Function(v) v.thevalue3tocompare = DDL3value)
End If

Dim your results = yourquery.ToList()   'only at this point the query is resolved and a call to the datbase will be made. 

end using
```